# Why does touch call the dup2() syscall?

Tags: file, unix, dup2

This is coming off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725129/why-does-touch-include-a-utimensat-syscall). Why is `touch` calling the dup2() syscall?

```
$ > strace touch 1 2>&1 | tail
close(3)                                = 0
open("1", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
utimensat(0, NULL, NULL, 0)             = 0
close(0)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a historical artifact.

The open()+dup2() pattern comes from the fd_reopen() function, which is used by several of the programs in the coreutils code base.

Prior to [coreutils commit e373bb1](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=e373bb19), fd_reopen() did not do open()+dup2(), but closed the desired file descriptor before opening a new one. This was the case when touch started using this function at [coreutils commit 478bd89](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=commitdiff;h=478bd8935b35f410beb59e9b1fcf844bb3aee34b). Per that commit message, the intent was to reduce the number of file descriptors touch would have open.

Comment: I filed [coreutils bug 31332](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31332) about this.